# How to create a navigation with subsections?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with subsections. The primary links are a list that is displayed inline and the subsections of the links over which the mouse is currently over should be displayed in another list under the primary list. I've currently accomplished this with a list that basically looks like this: 

`HTML`

```
<ul>
  <li id="one">Primary One</li>
  <li id="two">Primary Two</li>
  <li id="three">Primary Three</li>
  <li id="hidden-one">Secondary One</li>
  <li id="hidden-one">Secondary Two</li>
</ul>
```

`SASS`

```
#hidden-one {
  display: none;
}

#one:hover ~ #hidden-one {
  display: inline;
}
```

And that works to such a degree that the text appears if the mouse hovers over the Primary One element. But I can't click on the links, because they disappear when I'm moving the mouse away from the element to the secondary links.

I don't have any good idea how to accomplish that one can click those secondary elements. A javascript solution would be ok, even if I'm trying to avoid it.

Would be great if somebody had an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to have the sub-section in it's own unordered list. Insert the subsection <`ul`> inside the parent list <`li`>

Change your ***HTML*** to this:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">Primary One
        <ul>
            <li class="hidden-one"><a href="#">Secondary One</a></li>
            <li class="hidden-one"><a href="#">Secondary Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="two">Primary Two</li>
    <li id="three">Primary Three</li>
</ul>
```

***CSS:***

```
.hidden-one {
    display: none;
}
#one:hover > ul > .hidden-one {
  display: inline;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8u0a9sj/)**

Comment: How would I make the second list appear _below_ the first one?

Comment: Did you see my jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Yes, sorry, maybe I didn't clarify enough, what I wanted to do. The primary elements are supposed to be a list that is displayed inline the secondary ones are another list that is displayed inline below in a smaller font. I don't want the primary elements to move at all which is, as far as I have tried it, the implication of adding the secondary elements in the `<li>`-tag of the primary element. The secondary elements should appear really below the whole list of primary elements, not just below the element they are linked to.

Comment: So, I did it with adding `position: absolute;` and a position below the list to the css file for the subsection.